# Row echelon forms of $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 3\\ 2 & 7 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is this good?
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 7/2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$
My solution's manual has not put it into the answer.

Comment: I think that $7/2$ should be 3.

Comment: That is one of the solutions that the book gave.

Comment: I switched the two rows. Then divided the first one by 2. Then I substracted the first one from the second one. Then I divided the second row by -1/2.

Comment: OK, a simpler way is simply substract 2 times the first row from the second.

Comment: Yes. But I am not asking for a simple way. I am asking if my method is good. Is it?

Comment: Your method involves an unnecessary extra step. But yes, that would be the upper-triangular form.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by “row echelon form”. The simplest one is obtained by adding to the second row the first row multiplied by $-2$, giving
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then you can go on with elementary row operations except row swapping, provided you go “bottom up”. So you surely can add to the first row the second row multiplied by $-1/2$, but I wonder *why* you would do that.

Of course you could also swap the rows, then multiply the first by $1/2$ and add to the second row the first multiplied by $-1$, getting
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 7/2 \\
0 & -1/2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which becomes your matrix after multiplying the second row by $-2$. But, again, *why* swapping the rows?

There is no unique “row echelon form”. The *reduced* row echelon form is unique.

---

When is a matrix in *row echelon form*? Let's say we have an $m\times n$ matrix.

> 1. Set $k=0$
> 2. If $k+1>m$, declare success; otherwise set $k\leftarrow k+1$
> 3. If all coefficients in the $k$-th row are zero set $l\leftarrow n+1$; otherwise find the first nonzero coefficient; if this coefficient is not $1$, declare the matrix is not in row echelon form, otherwise set $l$ to the index of this column
> 4. Check if all coefficients in places $(i,j)$ with $i>k$ and $j<l$ are zero; if this fails, declare the matrix is not in row echelon form
> 5. Go to step 2

Perform the described algorithm; if you arrive at “declare success”, then the matrix is in row echelon form. Some variants don't require that the first nonzero coefficient in step 3 equals $1$.

For the *reduced row echelon form*, step 4 becomes

> 4$'$. Check if all coefficients in places $(i,j)$ sith $i>k$ and $j<l$ as well as coefficients in places $(i,l)$ with $i<k$ are zero; if this fails, declare the matrix is not in reduced row echelon form

In practice, a matrix is in row echelon form when Gaussian elimination can't be started without swapping rows.

Comment: Hi, I just tried different things to see what exactly is a "row echelon" form. My point is not to be efficient, but to grasp the definition of it.

Comment: @user154734 I've added an algorithm for checking REF.